# Data bars in Excel not accurate

Tags: excel, cell, conditional-formatting

I have added data bars to some percentage formatted cells in Excel.

[image]

As you can see, the bars do not accurately represent the percentages. For example, the 78% bar looks like 99%. I tried going to Conditional Formatting > Mange Rules, and changing the Minimum to percent = 0/maximum = Automatic, but that distorted the bars even worse. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: If you use percent, it displays the values as a percentage of the *range of values* (i.e. the difference between the lowest and highest value). So your lowest value will have no bar (0%), and the highest will have a full (100%) bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your maximum value to 1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So then does the option for setting limit types to percent just not work?

Comment: @OstenGibson Not sure what you mean. In this example, since he/she is using percent, a max value of 1 = 100% .

Comment: No just in your example you set data type to Number correct? The OP had theirs set to percent, which makes sense to most users. I guess I just had a wondering to as the use of the percent option.

Comment: Oh, I tend to think of percentages as numbers between 0 and 1. Just a preference I guess. But I just tried changing Number to Percent and 1 to 100%, but that doesn't work as desired.

Comment: That totally worked. I had changed the percentages to numbers (ex: 0.77) and set the min to 0 and max to 1 and then changed the format back to percent and it displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my own testing, I find that both the data bars and the color scales always seem to work in relation to existing numbers in the list, rather than in relation to a defined maximum - regardless of whether I set it to Number or Percent.  Setting it to Number APPEARED to work at first, but once I started adding and changing numbers, the conditional formatting lost all rhyme/reason.